# I want to randomize responses in Python for a custom Alexa skill, question-answer project

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit

I'm creating a skill for Alexa where she would answer a question "Who is right, me or ..." I followed a tutorial here https://medium.com/crowdbotics/how-to-build-a-custom-amazon-alexa-skill-step-by-step-my-favorite-chess-player-dcc0edae53fb
but I need to randomize Alexa responses

```
Player_LIST = ["me or my wife", "me or my husband"]
Player_BIOGRAPHY = {"me or my wife":"She is.",

"me or my husband":"He is."}
```

```
#------------------------------Part3--------------------------------
# Here we define the Request handler functions

def on_start():
    print("Session Started.")

def on_launch(event):
    onlunch_MSG = "Hi, you could say, for example: who is right me or my husband?"
    reprompt_MSG = "you can say, who is right, me or my wife?"
    card_TEXT = "Who is right, me or... ?."
    card_TITLE = "Choose your question."
    return output_json_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(onlunch_MSG, card_TEXT, card_TITLE, reprompt_MSG, False)

def on_end():
    print("Session Ended.")
```

```
#---------------------------Part3.1.1-------------------------------
# Here we define the intent handler functions

def player_bio(event):
    name=event['request']['intent']['slots']['player']['value']
    player_list_lower=[w.lower() for w in Player_LIST]
    if name.lower() in player_list_lower:
        reprompt_MSG = ""
        card_TEXT = "You've picked " + name.lower()
        card_TITLE = "You've picked " + name.lower()
        return output_json_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(Player_BIOGRAPHY[name.lower()], card_TEXT, card_TITLE, reprompt_MSG, False)
    else:
        wrongname_MSG = "Some questions may not yet be present in my database. Try to rephrase your sentence."
        reprompt_MSG = "For example, who is right, me or my wife?"
        card_TEXT = "Use the full question."
        card_TITLE = "Wrong question."
        return output_json_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(wrongname_MSG, card_TEXT, card_TITLE, reprompt_MSG, False)
```

When I say "Alexa, who is right, me or my wife?", she always says: "She is"
I want her to give me every time different responses like: He is or Him or her or listen to your wife! or of course you or any other answer. I tried to do this:

```
Player_BIOGRAPHY = {"me or my wife":"She is.",
"me or my wife":"you.",
"me or my wife":"Of course your wife",

"me or my husband":"He is.",
"me or my husband":"You are right.",
"me or my husband":"He is not right."}
```

but Alexa always picks only the last response "Of course your wife."
How can I randomize many of these responses? I don't know how to code, but if I have come this far, I will be able to do it with your help, please. I can post the whole code it's just twice as much as here.

Comment: Well Alexa is not wrong.... she is always right :P, well... jokes aside.... thegamer007 is good... u can also write your own random function... and filter responses yourself... its not hard to write a random function in python...

Comment: I really don't know how to do that. I tried to add that code 
 random.choice(Player_BIOGRAPHY[name.lower()])  in  #---------------------------Part3.1.1-------------------------------   instead of the last line where it says return ... . So did it so: return random.choice(Player_BIOGRAPHY[name.lower()]). It didn't work. I am not a programmer and really don't know the syntax. But I just want to make a skill for my life. Later I will use this skill to make a tutorial on something. I will just put my own values. It may be the first working version or this one w/ random responses.

Comment: have you imported random? `import random` ... you have add this line with the other import lines... then try again with the skill...

Comment: Yes I did because TheGamer007 showed me where and how. I just started to learn Python, because this app now works and it's a great incentive for me, even for my age. If you know a programming language just a little bit, there are platforms that will allow to use this little knowledge for great ideas. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Oh great.. Glad we can help... Please mark the answer as accepted so others can find it helpful too ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Player_BIOGRAPHY` is a `dict`, which means each key has only one value. If you initialize it as

```
Player_BIOGRAPHY = {"me or my wife":"She is.",
"me or my wife":"you.",
"me or my wife":"Of course your wife",

"me or my husband":"He is.",
"me or my husband":"You are right.",
"me or my husband":"He is not right."}
```

The actual print output is:

```
{'me or my wife': 'Of course your wife', 'me or my husband': 'He is not right.'}
```

What you should do is have a list of possible responses for each key, and then use something like `random.choice` in order to pick from the list. Like so,

```
Player_BIOGRAPHY = {"me or my wife": ["She is.","you.","Of course your wife"],

"me or my husband": ["He is.","You are right.","He is not right."]}
```

And for random selection (you need to `import random`)

```
random.choice(Player_BIOGRAPHY[name.lower()])
# This will select a random item from the list mapped to name.lower()
```

So your full code would be as follows:

```
import random # this can be at the top of the file too
def player_bio(event):
    name=event['request']['intent']['slots']['player']['value']
    player_list_lower=[w.lower() for w in Player_LIST]
    if name.lower() in player_list_lower:
        reprompt_MSG = ""
        card_TEXT = "You've picked " + name.lower()
        card_TITLE = "You've picked " + name.lower()
        return output_json_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(random.choice(Player_BIOGRAPHY[name.lower()]), card_TEXT, card_TITLE, reprompt_MSG, False)
    else:
        wrongname_MSG = "Some questions may not yet be present in my database. Try to rephrase your sentence."
        reprompt_MSG = "For example, who is right, me or my wife?"
        card_TEXT = "Use the full question."
        card_TITLE = "Wrong question."
        return output_json_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(wrongname_MSG, card_TEXT, card_TITLE, reprompt_MSG, False)
```

Comment: #I tried to change it, added options in square brackets and also I did this change below. It didn't work
#   HERE MY EDITS ACCORDING TO YOUR CODE
#   IT WAS:
#   return output_json_builder_with_reprompt_and_card (Player_BIOGRAPHY[name.lower()],  card_TEXT, card_TITLE, reprompt_MSG, True)
 
#   AND I PUT YOUR CODE IN THIS WAY <<<
        return random.choice(Player_BIOGRAPHY[name.lower()])
#  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

Comment: ########### I ALSO TRIED THIS BUT IT DIDN'T WORK ################## 
  return output_json_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(random.choice(Player_BIOGRAPHY[name.lower()]), card_TEXT, card_TITLE, reprompt_MSG, True)

Comment: @Dilshod I've edited my answer to include how the code should be. Let me know if any error is thrown, or if it doesn't work as you expect.

Comment: TheGamer007 - thank you very much. Alexa does everything as I wish. This website is great. I couldn't find help anywhere but you helped me. It will allow me to create so many voice models and make them sound like a real human and not a machine. I will also start learning Python. I will polish this skill and publish it!

Comment: I opened another question, can you please help me there too? https://stackoverflow.com/q/56403361/11556836